# is there any demo for eclipse cdt api use?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want to use the eclipse cdt api to resolve c++ code AST tree for code analysis.

base on the blow question answer, I try to create a default Workspace and project by java code. The Workspace init method require many IDE source support, when i fix one resouce issue, another comes. is there any demo for this?

[Using CDT without Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646503/using-cdt-without-eclipse)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to parser a single source file, it is enough to use **cdt.core** only. If you want to use the higher level(semantic) you need to replace a lot dependences about those IDE packages. I did a project using Eclipse-JDT and use JavaCore and Workspace to generate IJavaProject. It is similar with CDT. I also do some research about static-code-analysis using JDT/CDT.